# Handling TableView content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am looking at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) table view controller example by Apple, where the code is structured in a way that when the user taps on a tableviewcell the cel expands and shows some details. This is what I see before and after tapping:

[image]

**I have been given instructions to create a tab view controller where I show a detailed view controller when the cel is tapped.**

I am considering starting from this example to structure my code, however I am unsure whether or not the example from Apple does actually use a detail view controller when showing the quotes from the play (it seems to me that is uses custom UITableViewCell for the quotes which is different from a UIViewController). So do you reckon that I should display a separate View once the user taps on a cell to fulfill the requirements? I am a bit confused! **Do developers actually use separate UIViewControllers to show details of a cel in a UITableView?**

Also do you think **this example** shows a detail view controller after the user taps on a cel (image above)? UITableViewCell derives from UIView and not UIViewController..

sorry for the confused question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example doesn't use another view controller, it just adds rows to the table view. The sample code doesn't match your described requirements so it doesn't really make a good starting point.

A normal master-detail project does match your requirement. Start simple, look at overall projects before searching for code for specific things. Become familiar with the environment you're developing with.

Yes, developers use view controllers to show detail - when it is appropriate to their requirements / needs. There are many ways to skin a cat...

Comment: thanks for the reply. So do you reckon that a good way to do so is to create a ViewController with the details (e.g. with the same size of screen) and add this as subview to the RootViewController where the UITableView is added? Then I can add a tap recognizer to the custom cel and in the implementation of the action method for the tap send a local notification with the tag of the cell indexPath.. the RootViewController will be listening to the event and accessing to the tag of the notification received. In this way will be able to populate the detail view controller accordingly.

Comment: please let me know if the approach above would be best practice or if you have any other sample of code that I can study to solve this problem in the most robust way possible.. thanks!

Comment: You're making things so complicated. The delegate of the table view is told when a cell is tapped. Put it in a navigation controller and then just push your detail view when it's tapped. Seriously, search for a plain master-detail example.

Comment: Ah ah, how ignorant of me.. I did not even realize that Xcode provided a template for "Free". Its a great starting point, thanks for pointing it out..